# How to address JSON elements by number instead of name in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: arrays, json, azure-data-factory

I have this JSON response from a REST API:

```
},
"_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "https://api.com/rest/v1/lists?afterId=0&pageSize=10"
    },
    "next": {
        "href": "https://api.com/rest/v1/lists?afterId=17&pageSize=10"
    },
    "curies": [
        {
            "href": "https://apidocs.com/rest/v1/relations/{rel}",
            "name": "inx",
            "templated": true
        }
    ]
}
```

}

I need to access the "href" value below "next".
Sometimes, "next" changes to "upcoming".

Like this:

```
},
"_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "https://api.com/rest/v1/lists?afterId=0&pageSize=10"
    },
    "upcoming": {
        "href": "https://api.com/rest/v1/lists?afterId=17&pageSize=10"
    },
    "curies": [
        {
            "href": "https://apidocs.com/rest/v1/relations/{rel}",
            "name": "inx",
            "templated": true
        }
    ]
}
```

}

But the position is always the same.

Can I use something like this:

```
{"source":{"path":"$['_links']['self']['href']"},"sink":{"name":"thisIdLink"}},
{"source":{"path":"$['_links'][1]['href']"},"sink":{"name":"nextIdLink"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dataflow activity. Select Rest api as source.

Select flatten transformation for JSON. Now you can select index of `‘next’` or `‘upcoming’`.

[image]